# Setting listener without defining view?

Tags: android, performance, listener, onclicklistener, findviewbyid

Would this be recommended as something that would be okay to do:

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    //Do something
    }

});
```

Over:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton)

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    //Do something
    }

});
```

And is there any benefit (i.e performance) if any?

Comment: The first code is normally use for fast demo code, use the second code for code documentation, the performance is the same in both cases after compile the project.

Comment: If you want button only for onClick event than instead of using findViewById just define onClick in your layout xml file in attribute `android:onClick="myButtonClick"` and define only myButtonClick method in Activity. Thats it.. No need of define view. And again no performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference at all. Both will work the same with no difference in performance. But using the second solution you posted is better when developing apps. The first solution is just for quick code or demo use...